# How to return value from tkinter button callback

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a function that has a tkinter window defined and run inside of it. There is a button in that window, and I need the button to execute a `return` statement and return a value for the function.

The way to do things other than run argumentless functions from button callbacks seems to be `lambda`, but I can't figure out a way to do this with `lambda`, as any value returned from the lambda registers as the return value for the `lambda`.

The gist of my code is like this:

```
from tkinter import *

def function():
    root = Tk()

    entry = Entry(root)
    entry.pack()

    button = Button(root, text = "I'm a button", command = return entry.get()) #Does not work, you can't do this in a callback
    button.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to rewrite that return statement so that it is valid for the `command` argument.

Comment: `return` is useless with `Button` because there is nobody who can receive returned value.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really do that. The best way to do it is with a function but I'm not sure why you would want to do that. It seems a bit odd...  As commented, the a Tkinter script runs differently to a normal Python script so nothing will be able to use the returned value. Store it as a variable if you need it.

I would just create a function that stores it as a variable.

```
def foo():
    gah=entry.get()
    # return entry.get()
    # stuff or no stuff

button=Button(root, text="ghost", command=foo)
```

Comment: But it would be a local variable. Finally, I just use `global` for this (and ignore the feeling of sleaziness for using them :^| )

Comment: This serves no purpose because the local variable is immediately discarded when the function returns. Declaring `gah` a global *might* work as long as `foo` is defined in the same module with the code that references the global variable).