# How to pass a variable to a function via a Button?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I have defined the following functions in a module called `script.py`

```
def load_file():
    file_name = filedialog.askopenfile(filetypes=['EXE files', '*.exe'])
    return file_name   

def simulation(input_path, input_par): # this works fine
    # the functionruns an EXE file ang gives me two lists lst1 and lst2
    return lst1, lst2
```

Now the following button defined in the `main.py` calls the `load_file` function and it works fine (I print the path from within the function in the terminal). What I cannot figure out is how to pass the path I get within the `load_file` function as argument `input_path` to the function simulation via the button within the `main.py`.

```
input_var = #??
button = Button(frame_file, text='Open file', command=load_file)
button.grid(row=1, column=1)
simulation(input_path, input_var)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common way to do it when working with `tkinter` is to use `lambda` functions. The tricky part is getting the return value back because the return value of `command=` functions is ignored. Folks often use `global` variables to workaround that, but that tactic won't work if the function is defined in another module. Fortunately `tkinter` has several type-specific container [`Variable`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201031100214id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) subclasses that can be passed as arguments to such functions that will permit values to be retrieved from them.

Here's runnable code showing one way of using them to do this:

**`script.py`**

```
from tkinter import filedialog

def load_file(input_path):
    file_name = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('EXE files', '*.exe')])
    input_path.set(file_name)

def simulation(input_path, input_par): # this works fine
    # the function runs an EXE file ang gives me two lists lst1 and lst2
    return lst1, lst2
```

**`main.py`**

```
from script import load_file, simulation
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
frame_file = tk.Frame(root)
frame_file.pack()

input_path = tk.StringVar()
input_var = 42
button = tk.Button(frame_file, text='Open file', command=lambda: load_file(input_path))
button.grid(row=1, column=1)
button2 = tk.Button(frame_file, text='Run simulation',
                    command=lambda: simulation(input_path.get(), input_var))
button2.grid(row=1, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

#### Update

Here's a slightly more complicated but much more flexible version, that would work with many more types of return values, including user-defined classes (not just the four `tkinter` supports — bool, float, int, string). Supporting more types of returned data automatically, also means that called functions don't need to be modified.

It does this by defining a `CallBack` class whose instances "wrap" the functions to be called and save their return values in a tkinter `StringVar` widget so they can be retrieved later as needed by calling a method `get_result()` that instances of the class have. To work with more datatypes it uses Python's built-in [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#module-pickle) module to temporarily store the data.

**`script2.py`**

```
from tkinter import filedialog

def load_file():
    file_name = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('EXE files', '*.exe')])
    return file_name

def simulation(input_path, input_par): # this works fine
    # the function runs an EXE file and gives me two lists lst1 and lst2
    print(f'simulation({input_path=}, {input_par=}) called')
    list1, list2 = ['param', input_par], list('spam')
    return list1, list2
```

**`main2.py`**

```
from script2 import load_file, simulation
import pickle
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


class CallBack:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.var = tk.StringVar()
    def get_result(self):
        pickled_result = self.var.get()
        return pickle.loads(pickled_result.encode('latin1'))  # Unpickle and return it.
    def __call__(self):
        res = self.func()
        pickled_result = pickle.dumps(res).decode('latin1')  # Pickle result.
        self.var.set(pickled_result)  # And save it in tkinter StringVar.


root = tk.Tk()
frame_file = tk.Frame(root)
frame_file.pack()

input_par = 42
callback1 = CallBack(load_file)  # Wrap function from other module.

button = tk.Button(frame_file, text='Open file', command=callback1)
button.grid(row=1, column=1)

def run_sim():
    """ Run simulation function and display value returned. """
    # Wrap other function in other module to allow results to be retrieved.
    callback2 = CallBack(lambda: simulation(callback1.get_result(), input_par))
    callback2()  # Call the function and save its return value.
    results = callback2.get_result()  # Get function's return value.
    messagebox.showinfo(title='Simulation Results', message=str(results))

button2 = tk.Button(frame_file, text='Run simulation', command=run_sim)
button2.grid(row=1, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! Now it works. So basically you define a global variable in the main, given as input in the function in the module, and then it is set from within the function in the module, right? Could StringVar be a list?

Comment: You're welcome. The variable doesn't have to be a global in main, just something with a existing long enough so it's available whenever it's needed (which can often but not always rule out local variables). One alternative is an attribute of an instance of a class. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69272154/how-to-update-a-variable-in-tkinter-app-without-using-global/69276698#69276698) of mine for an example. A `StringVar` can't be a list, but you could have a list-of-`StringVars`, or a dictionary with values of that type (or one of the others).

Comment: Also note that tkinter `Variable` classes have other uses which make creating your GUI easier. For example when you create a `Button` or `Label` widget, you can specify the text that they display through either a `text=` or a `textvariable=` option. If you use the latter, and later on something in the program changes the value of the specified `StringVar` variable, the widget associated with it will also automatically be updated (as in you don't have to manually reconfigure it or them).

Comment: @drSlump: Just added an update that should allow functions to return lists and many other types.

Comment: thanks. so the textvarible must be a StringVar if I want to update its value during the program?

Comment: The function return value doesn't have to be a string, it can almost anything. The class *uses* a `StringVar` internally to store the pickled data, but that doesn't limit the type of data that can be stored. I'll modify my update to illustrate this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `partial` method to pass parameters.

```
simulation = partial(simulation, input_path, input_par)  
buttonCal = tk.Button(root, text="Simulate", command=simulation)
```

Comment: thanks a lot!. But I want to have a button to save the path and a button to run the simulation. Actualy I will have several button for several kind of simulation. Is that actually possible?

Comment: If you have to return values, you can check out this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099908/python-tkinter-return-value-from-function-used-in-command

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is a duplicate, it's just not apparent from the title, because it is worded a bit weirdly:

[How to return value from tkinter button callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34255782/how-to-return-value-from-tkinter-button-callback)

I can propose a solution other than what's in the thread, but it's admittedly not clean.

You can use a lambda,  or the already mentioned `partial` method to pass a mutable object, as described by @vnk. Using lambdas (or partially applied functions) is the usual way to pass arguments to Tkinter callbacks.

Since I assume that your path is probably a string, which is immutable, you should either use an object such as a pathlike.Path, or create an object yourself and wrap your path string into it. Unfortunately, your callback has to cooperate for this as well.

```
path_container = [] # You could define a class to have cleaner code than having to use the magic 0 index.

tk.Button(root, text="Open file", command=(lambda: load_file(path_container)))
# Your load_file has to know that its argument is a list whose 0-th element must  contain the path,
# or, if you opt for the more readable approach, that the .path attribute of your
# path container object should be used.
```

If you go really wild, you can even create a function just to change a mutable object, so you don't have to change your `load_file` function:

```
def store_path(path_container, path):
    path_container[0] = path # Or path_container.path = path, if you're doing it cleaner.

tk.Button(root, text="Open file", command=(lambda: store_path(path_container, load_file())))
```

A lambda is useful because it captures variables from the parent scope, such as `path_container`.
A helper is needed because of the limitation applying to lambdas that their body must be a single expression, which an assignment (in reality, name binding) is not, in Python. It is in many other languages, such as C.

Honestly, the most sensible solution is probably to design your callback to use a pathlib.Path object. If your program grows large, you will benefit from having a proper path class instead of a string anyway, even if you don't use Tkinter.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback. I do not get why it is so complicate. It seems to me such a distorted way of manage it by tkinter.

Comment: @drSlump It is complicated because Tkinter is just an interface to a Tcl interpreter built into Python, and Tcl is an ancient language where using global state is accepted convention, so their callback mechanism works like this, which is in turn mirrored by Tkinter. You could also use globals to exchange information, but even the mutable local solution I provided is a lot better than that.

EDIT: I edited the answer to emphasize that I think using pathlib.Path in your callback would be the best solution, independently of Tkinter.

Comment: thanks. Is tkinter the only option to create pthon based GUI?

Comment: @drSlump, No, not at all. In fact, for modern GUIs, it's the one that's definitely not recommended, as you can not create operating system-native widgets in it.
There is PyQt6, PySide (official as opposed to PyQt, but lagging behind in development), and wxWidgets. There are also Python bindings for GTK, I believe.

Comment: @Larry: While you're right about that other question being a duplicate, it unfortunately doesn't not have an accepted answer and the one answer it does have is wrong (and even if it were fixed, it wouldn't help when the function being called is in another module as is the case here. However you're wrong about `tkinter` not being able to create OS-native widgets (see the `ttk`-themed widget it contains). Also, the fact that `tkinter` is now part of the standard library gives it distinct advantage over most if not all of its competition, as you might imagine.

Comment: @martineau I was also dissatisfied with the approach the other answers took, which is why I tried to provide an alternative here. I see, I did not know about tkinter's native GUI capabilities. Yes, being part of the standard library is an advantage across the board, but not necessarily. E.g. on Windows, it is common to distribute library dependencies with the application itself, and on many Linux-based distros, the mentioned toolkits are included in central repositories.